# TCPDF: writeHTML ignores margin right definition

Tags: html, margin, tcpdf

I use the `writeHTML()` function in TCPDF to write HTML using `setPageRegions()` function so it floats around a picture. It works fine. But the only problem I have is, the text is going to the very right end of the page.

I set the margins with `SetMargins(20, 20, 20)` and I also set the margins and with of the html container with the style attribute, but it ignores it all.

How can i get the text width a margin on the right side. Left side is fine.

This is my code:

```
$pdf->SetMargins( 20, 20);
$pdf->Image( $img, 25, 80, 100, 128, 'JPEG', '', 'N', 0);
$txt = "<p style=\"width:380px;margin-right:20px;text-align:justify;color:rgb( 54,111,148);font-size:12pt;line-height:1px;\">... my long text ...</p>";
$pdf->SetXY( 25, 80);
$regions = array( array( 'page' => '', 'xt' => 135, 'yt' =>  80, 'xb' => 135, 'yb' =>  215, 'side' => 'L')); // the region where the picture is located incl. paddings
$pdf->setPageRegions( $regions);
$pdf->writeHTML( $txt, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Thanks for any help.